# c# Winforms application with CefSharp Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime-error, cefsharp

Got an issue with the build for a Winform application. Keep getting the could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core error message during runtime of a build. I don't get the same issue in debug mode.

CefSharp version is 79.1.360.

The project structure at a basic level is:

- Startup project
- Component project (where the Custom Chromium Browser user control resides)
- UI project

The platform target is AnyCPU.

I've installed Cefsharp as per this site's [instructions](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application):

For the project setup I've got the CefSharpAnyCpuSupport tag set to true in both the Startup project and the Component project.

Prefer 32-bit is ticked in the Startup project. For the other projects it is read only.

The App.config for both Component & Startup projects have been modified as per the instructions.

The nuget packages I've noted as appearing in UI project packages folder.

The references in the Components project for all have "copy to output" set to  "copy always." There's 3 references (CefSharp, CefSharp.Core, CefSharp.Winforms)

And tried to resolve this issue by doing the following:

- Uninstall and reinstall CefSharp
- Tried to resolve using the cefsharp github [faq](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies).
- Tested having the UI project having all the same app settings and references, same goes for the other projects.

The required dll's all appear in the bin folder for both debug and release. Each machine, where the build is created and where the actual program is tested have the correct Visual Studio c++ redistributables installed 2013/2015 for x64 and x86.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and resolved this? I've already searched every previous Stackoverflow query regarding this and none of those have solutions that work for this application. Not sure if there's an issue because we use InstallShield for the builds/publishing which I haven't noticed anyone else using.

Please let me know if there's any further information you require to assist. Thanks,

Update: Bin folder contents post build

[Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kon7i.png)

Comment: You shouldn't change the reference properties to copy always,  that'll break AnyCpu. What exactly does install shield have to do with the problem?  Are you seeing the problem on your development machine?  Make sure you can bind deploy to the target machine.

Comment: I’ve done builds with and without copy always set to true. It was a solution in other tickets. Neither option worked. Not sure what you mean by bind deploy. Basically with install shield when were creating a patch we switch to release mode and rebuild and it creates an .msi file to install on other machines.

Comment: Don't modify copy always, it'll only add to the problem you are seeing. The CefSharp dependencies will only be copied to the bin folder of the project that directly references them and it'll work for a project that directly references the project that references CefSharp, this is a msbuild limitation. Make sure that libcef.dll and all the bin and pak files are present,  I cannot link to the reference on GitHub that lists them all as GitHub appears to be down.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a screenshot of the bin folder contents. It's included at the bottom. I had already checked the Github FAQ to check the required files were there. Same files are in Release\bin\x86 and x64 folders

Comment: Please answer my other questions. Are you seeing the problem on your development machine? Make sure you can bind deploy to the target machine

Comment: The official `AnyCPU` instructions are at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 please follow those instead of the ourcodeworld article which is not an official guide written by myself (last time I read it there were mistakes). Based on what you've described I'd probably go with option 3.

Comment: Hi @amaitland It doesn't work if I deploy onto the development machine. I've been working on Option 1 & 3 from that document and neither option worked. Well tbh option 3 is not ideal as we don't want to give users write privileges for the program files folders.

Comment: Another option I'm trying is to move the Chromium Browser control to the UI project since that is where the cefsharp packages are installed via nuget. Still getting the same error but will try again with a cleaner install as .csproj, app.configs and packages.config files have all been manually changed. Its not very clean atm.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes,  make sure it runs on the target machines, then once thats working make it AnyCpu and work from there. Without an example that demos your structure I really cannot say anything further.

Comment: Hi @amaitland I've tried to simplify the structure and have just installed for my UI project. When setting up the solution, after I've installed cefsharp.Winforms via nuget what is the correct way to add the references to the project? To resolve errors I've had to add the references via the packages folder, and have had to choose the CefSharp.dll, CefSharp.Core.dll & CefSharp.Winforms.dll from one of the x86/x64 folders.

Comment: I've also tried Option 2 from that link you sent. The assembly resolver does not find any assembly that starts with CefSharp.

Comment: Remove the references you manually added, that will break assembly resolve. You just need to restart visual studio after installing the packages as per the post installation instructions https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/NuGet/Readme.txt#L12

Comment: Yeah I did the restart, but the "using CefSharp;" statements in each class were giving errors as if the reference doesn't exist.

Comment: If you add references then the dlls will be copied to the bin directory and the assembly resolve event won't be called. Have you tested with the minimum example as requested?

Comment: I've tested with the minimal example. Had to create a separate platform for AnyCPU in the Visual Studio Configuration Manager in order to mirror my app. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Fork the minimum example and push your changes to GitHub. Squash your changes into a single commit.  Post a link to your fork. Please specify which AnyCpu implementation you choose.

Comment: Hi @amaitland thanks for your help, sorry for the late reply. We've basically resolved this issue by just targeting x86. I appreciate your patience, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all the CefSharp required files and folders from Debug folder into the Release folder and kept the rest of the release build as they are, and my issue resolved.